# Change the title name

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, title

I have a simple question to ask. I have a site in which i want to change the title name on the page on load or maybe without code too.

i have attached the picture of the title that i am referring to.
[image]

Hope you guys can help.

Comment: is `Test_site` the name of the site that you have created ?

Comment: yes it is the name of the site that i have created.

Comment: this seems to be your custom page with Custom title

Comment: yes how do i change this any idea.
On load of the website i want to change the name of the title.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to can the tilte of the site on page level then use the script below

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
   //To change site title
   document.getElementById("DeltaPlaceHolderPageTitleInTitleArea").innerHTML="New Site Title";

  //To change the page title
jQuery(document).attr('title', 'New Name');
});

</script>
```

And if you want to change it across site level the go to master page from SharePoint Designer and open the master.html file and find the **"DeltaPlaceHolderPageTitleInTitleArea"** and add your title name to it.

Comment: i do not have the access to master page actually. is there any ohter way to do it on site level

Comment: any script that is referenced in master pages

Comment: i am not aware of it actually !

Comment: if you have page edit permissions, please try to add script editor webpart to the page and paste the script given above

Answer (score 1):

Site title is set by:

- Go to "Site Settings"
- "Title description and logo"

Comment: Tried that but it did not work.

Comment: Can you elaborate on this? Changing the ***Site Settings > Title, description and logo*** will always work. If it does not work for you, chances are that you don't have permissions to change it or you are not following the correct steps. Post screen shots of what you tried and what did not work.

Comment: Then it sounds like your custom master page is not using the site title. It is possible it is using the page title. Edit the page and change the title of the page.